# Is it bad practice in JavaScript to bind "this" to functions to only import several other functions once?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad practice to have code like the following?

```
this.testFun       = require("./testFun");
this.otherFun      = require("./otherFun");
this.yetAnotherFun = require("./yetAnotherFun");

exportFun1 = require("./exportFun1");
exportFun2 = require("./exportFun2");
exportFun3 = require("./exportFun3");

myModule = {
  exportFun1: exportFun1.bind(this);
  exportFun2: exportFun2.bind(this);
  exportFun3: exportFun3.bind(this);
}
```

I assume it is not preferable because I haven't seen it done anywhere. If not, what is the best way to avoid repeating a set of imports in several files that all need them? That is, how do I avoid importing `testFun`, `otherFun`, and `yetAnotherFun` in each of the `exportFun`s?

Comment: why do you want to avoid importing the modules inside the `exportFun`'s ? ( in any event I wouldn't use `this` to communicate dependencies )

Comment: because there are actually like 10 `exportFun`s and 8 imports and it seems really redundant to write those import statements, so I'd like to keep it a little dry-er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing in dependencies like this to your `exportFun` modules is gonna make it impossible for a reader to deduce what the actually dependencies are since they are only set at runtime and they come in to play trough the `this` keyword which ( I think ) can look really awkward.

Instead of doing this I would isolate the shared code between the `exportFun`'s in it's own file.
Maybe use a base class ( if applicable ) Then you can just `require` this shared module inside your `exportFun` modules.

Comment: There really isn't any code redundancy, just things like, e.g. calling functions that I've already separated out because they were redundant. But I suppose I'll just have to live with what I have. Thanks!